# Can't fire click event on the elements with same id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could you help me to understand - where I made the mistake. I have the following html code:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.ru" id="getInfo" onClick="return false;">Info mail.ru</a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.com" id="getInfo" onClick="return false;">Info mail.com</a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.net" id="getInfo" onClick="return false;">Info mail.net</a>
</div>
```

and the following js code (using jQuery):

```
$('#getInfo').click(function(){
    alert('test!');
});
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dizpers/Xde7K/)

"Click" event fired only on first link element. But not on others.

I know that each **ID** in html page should be used only one time (but **CLASS** can be used a lot of times) - but it only **should** (not **must**) as I know. Is it the root of my problem?

TIA!

**upd:** Big thx to all for explanation!:)

Comment: Do not reuse `ID`s. This is your problem. Use a class for this.

Comment: [By definition, the id attribute must be unique.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id)

Comment: so, it's not a recomendation (should), but the hard rule (must)?

Comment: It's a Bad Idea™ because you will get unexpected behavior in certain cases (like this one). `ID` attributes are *meant* to point to one element. Use it like this and you will not have any issues. Use `CLASS` attributes to group elements together.

Comment: It says "must": http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Consider the HTML Living Standard instead of HTML 4 - it's newer and **updated regularly**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a class for this (and `return false` in your handler, not inline):

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.ru" class="getInfo">Info mail.ru</a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.com" class="getInfo">Info mail.com</a>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.net" class="getInfo">Info mail.net</a>
</div>

$('.getInfo').click(function(){
    alert('test!');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xde7K/2/

The reason you're having this problem is that elements are retrieved by `ID` using `document.getElementById()`, which can only return one element. So you only get one, whichever the browser decides to give you.

Answer (score 4):

While you ***must***, according to the W3 specifications, have only one element with a given id within any document, you can bypass this rule, and the issues arising from the consequences if `document.getElementById()`, if you're using jQuery, by using:

```
$('a[id="getInfo"]').click(function() {
    alert('test!');
    return false;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Xde7K/3/).

***But***, please, ***don't***. Respect the specs, they make everybody's life easier when they're followed. The above is a possibility, but using html correctly is much, much better for us all. And reduces the impact of any future changes within the browser engines, jQuery or JavaScript itself.

Comment: Because the simple `$('#getInfo')` implements the native `document.getElementById()` (note that it's 'Element', not 'Elements') which is designed to abide by the W3 specs, and to return only *one* element. Using the [`[attribute="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) iterates over all the `a` elements in the page and tests whether the attribute does, in fact, equal the given value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same id for several element (although the page won't validate), but then you can't use the id to find the elements.

The `document.getElementById` method only returns a single element for the given id, so if you would want to find the other elements you would have to loop through all elements and check their id.

The Sizzle engine that jQuery uses to find the elements for a selector uses the `getElementById` method to find the element when given a selector like `#getInfo`.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It must only be used once or it will be invalid so use a class instead, return false can also be added to your jQuery code as so: -

```
$('.getInfo').click(function(){
    alert('test!');

    return false;
});


<a href="#info-mail.net" **class**="getInfo" ....
```

Answer (score 1):

First id's are for one element only, you should have same id for several divs.

you can make it class instead.

your example changed:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.ru" class="getInfo" >Info mail.ru</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.com" class="getInfo" >Info mail.com</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="#info-mail.net" class="getInfo" >Info mail.net</a>
</div>


$('.getInfo').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();    //this is for canceling your code : onClick="return false;"
    alert('test!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and as everyone suggested, there should not be elements with duplicate IDs. But sometimes it cannot be helped as someone else may have written the HTML code.

For those cases, you can just expand the selector used to force jQuery to use `querySelectorAll` internally instead of `getElementById`. Here is a  sample code to do so:

```js
$('body #getInfo').click(function(){
    alert('test!');
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
      <a href="#info-mail.ru" id="getInfo" onClick="return false;">Info mail.ru</a>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
      <a href="#info-mail.com" id="getInfo" onClick="return false;">Info mail.com</a>
  </div>
  <div id="container">
      <a href="#info-mail.net" id="getInfo" onClick="return false;">Info mail.net</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

However as David Thomas said in his answer

> ***But***, please, ***don't***. Respect the specs, they make everybody's life easier when they're followed. The above is a possibility, but using html correctly is much, much better for us all. And reduces the impact of any future changes within the browser engines, jQuery or JavaScript itself.